# How can I debug Rspec in RubyMine using Docker?

Tags: docker, rspec, rubymine

The CLI command I use to run the file is:

`bin/rspec ryanf_test_spec.rb`

I would like to debug this file.

I use: Ruby mine & docker has to be up & running for this to work (`docker-compose up`).

Comment: Why does Docker need to be part of this setup?  Can you use a Ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm, and run your debugger locally without Docker?

Comment: You can configure Docker based Ruby SDK and then run and debug your RSpec tests using the corresponding RSpec Run configuration (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#run_tests)